# Концепты не работают

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++20, concept, концепты

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::signed_integral T>
std::make_unsigned_t<T> unsign(T x) {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    unsign(42);
    unsign(42.);
}
```

Почему 2 вызов не компилируется из-за ошибки в `std::make_unsigned_t<T>`, а не из-за несоответствия типа концепту? Как исправить?

> error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
> 'std::__make_unsigned_selector<double, false, false>'
> { typedef typename __make_unsigned_selector<_Tp>::__type type; };

Comment: если посмотреть чуточку ниже на строку в ошибках, то там будет видно то, что Вы похоже и хотите `instantiation of template class 'std::make_unsigned<double>' requested here
    using make_unsigned_t = typename make_unsigned<_Tp>::type;`

Comment: @KoVadim я хочу `candidate: 'template<class T>  requires  signed_integral<T> std::make_unsigned_t<T> foo(T)'`/`constraints not satisfied`/т.п.

Comment: а кто то такой уже видели? (я просто нигде)

Comment: @KoVadim да, если заменить `std::make_unsigned_t<T>` на просто `T`, то будет ожидаемая ошибка

Comment: видимо make_unsigned_t должен быть также обложен концептом, но его не обложили. С другой стороны, gcc более прозрачен в отличии от clang

Comment: Рассказывайте, чем это собиралось и с какими флагами. А лучше сразу со ссылкой на онлайн компилятор. И не непопулярное мнение: концепты фактически бесполезны, делайте static_assert

Comment: @user7860670 https://godbolt.org/z/fjMv5TaxP

Comment: @user7860670 сами концепты как задум - чудесны, но вот тулинг в компиляторах ещё не подтянулся на достаточный уровень.  Да, с++ это тяжело. Да, здесь нужно  думать.

Answer (score 4):

Это минус концептов, наверное единственный по сравнению с обычным SFINAE.

Они (и концепты, и `requires`) проверяются поздно - уже после того, как шаблонный аргумент подставляется в возвращаемый тип и т. п.

Возможные решения:

- Завернуть `std::make_unsigned_t` в свой `using` с концептом на шаблонном параметре.
- Использовать обычный SFINAE.